# Enable debug mode interactively in symfony

Tags: php, debugging, symfony1

I'm using symfony 1.4 with Doctrine.

I'm trying to find a way to enable debug mode only if the current `sfUser` has a special `debugger` credential.

I already created a filter that deactivates the symfony debug bar if the `sfUser` has not this credential (the `web_debug` is set to `true` in my `settings.yml` file):

```
class checkWebDebugFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute($filterChain)
  {
    if(!$this->getContext()->getUser()->hasCredential('debugger'))
    {
      sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);
    }

    $filterChain->execute();
  }
}
```

The code of my `index.php` file is:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false));
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

The problem is, as the `debug` mode is hardcoded to `false` in my `index.php`, it is also disabled for debuggers; therefore the Web debug bar does not show Doctrine statements nor timing indications.

Is there a way to enable debug mode only if the current `sfUser` has a precise credential?

I tried to add `sfConfig::set('sf_debug', true);` to my `checkWebDebugFilter::execute()` method but as the filter is executed *after* Doctrine statements, they are not recorded.

I also tried to add `session_start();` in my `index.php` file, then browsing through the `$_SESSION` variable to check whether the current user has the `debugger` credential, but it did not work (and it was not in the spirit of symfony either).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think the best approach is setting another context when the the user has the credential. I'm working with a solution but yet coudn't make it work

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the debug parameter in the index.php file, it actually is passed down to the sfApplicationConfiguration class of your application. In your case it can be found in the **/apps/frontend/config/frontendConfiguration.class.php** file. frontendConfiguration class extends sfApplicationConfiguration, and here you can add your code.

Debug parameter is stored in a protected variable of this class, so you wont be able to change it from filter, but you can create a function for example:

```
setDebug($mode) {
   $this->debug = $mode;
}
```

And call it in your filter:

```
$this->context->getConfiguration()->setDebug(true);
```

You also could override isDebug() function in frontendConfiguration class, because that is used in the initConfiguration() function to initialize timing indicators and other debugging stuff.

```
if ($this->isDebug() && !sfWebDebugPanelTimer::isStarted())
{
    sfWebDebugPanelTimer::startTime();
}
```

But you won't be able to check user permissions here, as sfUser class won't be initialized in this stage yet. But you can check $_COOKIES or $_SESSION global variables for a value that you can set when user is logging in. Or you can call sfWebDebugPanelTimer::startTime() in your Filter, but will miss a few microseconds.

I have not tested this, but that's how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks about that. I tried the second solution, but `session_start()` seems not to be called before `frontendConfiguration.class.php` as I was getting some **Undefined variable: _SESSION** notices.

Comment: Or maybe symfony unsets the `_SESSION` global array after initializing its sfUser...

Answer (score -1):

Try this

if you want to enable web_debug panel (dev) mode then

http://host_url/frontend_dev.php

or

write in your index.php 'frontend','dev',true.

require_once(dirname(**FILE**).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
**$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true));**
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid you did not understand the question; the problem is not activating debug mode but activating it _interactively_. It means I'm finding a way to change the contents of `index.php` _depending_ on the current `sfUser` (and one of its credentials).